# Раздельная компиляция

Tags: project

В каких случаях нужна перекомпиляция зависимых файлов?

Comment: Вообще не вижу смысла сильно этим заморачиваться: за вас все решит IDE или maven )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем ясна суть вопроса.

Допустим у нас есть два класса: `A` и `B`, зависящий от `А`, например

```
// A.java
public class A {}

// B.java
public class B extends A {}
```

При компиляции с "чистого листа" файла `B.java` командой `javac B.java` автоматически будет скомпилирован и `A.java`

Если `A.class` уже есть в наличии и изменения были только в `B.java` - пересобираться `A.java` не будет.

Если `A.class` уже есть в наличии, но вы изменили и `A.java` и `B.java` - при сборке `B.java` будет скомпилирован и `A.java`.

При этом, в обратную сторону это не работает: если вы пересобираете `A.java`, то `B.java` пересобран не будет - компилятор не пересобирает автоматически зависимые от текущего классы. Таким образом можно словить при запуске программы ошибку `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`, если `B` вызовет метод из `A`, которого в нем уже нет.

Comment: А как решают эту проблему в больших проектах? "автоматически зависимые от текущего классы" maven разве это может?

Comment: @fuXingproblem maven как раз создан для работы с многочисленными зависимостями.

Comment: @fuXingproblem, никак не решают. Пишут в командной строке `mvn compile` и идут пить чай. Maven все решит.